# Iterating through a generator of itertools.combinations object takes forever

Tags: python, list, generator, combinations, variance

***Edit::***
after all these discussions with juanpa & fusion here in the comments and Kevin on [python chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) , i have come to a conclusion that `iterating` through a `generator` takes the same time as it would take `iterating` through any other object because generator itself generates those `combinations` on the fly. Moreover the approach by fusion worked great for `len(arr)` up to `1000`(maybe up to `5k` - but it terminates due to time out, of course on an online judge - Please Note it is not because of trying to get the `min_variance_sub`, but I also have to get the `sum of absolute differences` of all the pairs possible in the `min_variance_sub`). I am going to accept fusion's approach as an answer for this question, because it answered the question.
But I will also create a new question for that problem statement (more like a `QnA`, where I will also answer the question for `future visitors` - i got the answer from submissions by other candidates, an `editorial` by problem setter, and a code by problem setter himself - though I do not understand the approach they used). I will link to the other question as I create it :)
***It's [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63774153/10145519)***

## The original question starts below

I'm using `itertools.combinations` on an array so first up I tried something like

```
aList = [list(x) for x in list(cmb(arr, k))]
```

where cmb = `itertools.combinations`, arr is the list, and k is an int.
This works totally good for len(arr) < 20 or so but this Raised a `MemoryError` when len(arr) became 50 or more.

On a suggestion by kevin on Python Chat, I used a `generator`, and it worked amazingly fast in generating those combinations like this

```
aGen = (list(x) for x in cmb(arr, k))
```

But It's so slow to iterate through this generator object.
I tried something like

```
for p in aGen:
    continue
```

and even this code seems to take forever.

Kevin also suggested an answer talking about `kth combination` which was nice but in my case I actually want to test all the possible combinations and select the one with `minimum variance`.

***So what would be the memory efficient way of checking all the possible combinations of an array (a list) to have `minimum variance` (to be precise, I only need to consider sub arrays having exactly k number of elements)***

Thank You For Any Help.

Comment: What is k here? Almost certainly, you are just working with very many combinations.

Comment: Note, `aGen = (list(x) for x in cmb(arr, k))` doesn't generate the combinations, it creates *a generator* which generates the combinations on the fly as you iterate over it. So of course it's very fast, it doesn't really do any work

Comment: in the current case len(arr) is 50, and k is 8. And yes the number of combinations is definitely a lot.

Comment: @juanpa I see. so is it more or less like the kth combination thingy (of course without actually having indexed combinations) ?

Comment: 50 choose 8 is 536,878,650. Half a billion iterations. Assuming the work you do on each iteration takes, say, 1 millisecond then it would require `536878650 * 1e-3 / (60*60) == 149.13295833333333` hours to complete. Now, perhaps the work you are doing on each iteration is less, but that gives you a good idea how long this could potentially take. What operation are you doing with each combination?

Comment: :O I will be doing some heavy task on each iteration. To be precise, check the `variance `of each sub array (or a sub list) and select the one with the `minimum variance` (i will use `statistics.variance()` to calculate variance because the naive approach will only add more operations resulting in disastrous time complexity).

Comment: Actually, the naive-approach might be better, the `statistics` package has to handle various different numeric typs, and it takes great care, so there's a lot of overhead. I don't think the time complexity would be different in any case, but of course, here constant factors matter

Comment: I would consider that. But the thing is the program doesn't even reach anywhere near the point where I actually make use of either the naive approach or `statistics`. It can't get past `for p in aGen: continue `  block of code. 

And unfortunately I am supposed to this whole process in under a few seconds (It is actually one of the hard algorithmic challenges on `hackerrank.com`).

I am starting to think Python is not really suitable for those tasks (or it may roughly be the same case with other langs.)

Is there a way around this or it has to to take hours to achieve what I intend?

Comment: Trust me when I say there are test cases with len(arr) beyond 10^5 for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the list with `n` elements first,

Then use a moving window of k length along the sorted list.

And find the minimum variance of the `n-k+1` possible combinations.

The minimum should be the minimum of all combinations.

```py
 
def myvar(arr):
    l = len(arr)
    m = sum(arr)/l
    return sum((i-m)**2 for i in arr)/l


input_list = [.......]

sorted_list = sorted(input_list)

variance = None
min_variance_sub = None
for i in range(len(sorted_list) - k + 1):
    sub = sorted_list[i:i+k]
    var = myvar(sub)
    if variance is None or var<variance:
        variance = var
        min_variance_sub=sub
print(min_variance_sub)
```

Comment: Is that a way to partition the problem for parallel execution?

Comment: @Pynchia Sure, you can split the `sorted_list` into overlapping chunks with `k` overlap, then use `multiprocessing` to compute minimum variance for each chunk, then combine the results and find the global minimum.

Comment: OK thanks. Apart from the multiprocessing, please expound with examples, as your answer isn't clear enough, too concise

Comment: @Pynchia Do you want examples for the answer to 'how to find the minimal variance' or 'how to partition the problem for parallel execution'?

Comment: @fusion I appreciate your response. But the thing is the online judge system will not allow numpy (or any module which is not in the official python distro) so your approach is totally valid but it won't work in my case though.

Comment: @PSSolanki In that case, you can write your own variance calculator function. See my edits above.

Comment: Alright, i'ma give that a go. and will let u know of the outcome.

Comment: @fusion It worked totally well, but seems like it doesn't check all the possible combinations (each having exactly `k` elements) OR it includes duplicate combinations (I can't figure out which one is the the case). 

After i get the `min_variance_sub` I need to find sum of all the absolute differences between elements (& i'm able to do that by creating `itertools.combinations` of 2 elements each and getting the `abs` difference).

Your approach worked well for `len(arr) < 20` but it gives wrong answer for `len(arr) >= 20`

Comment: If you can move this convo to a chat room (as suggested by SO), I would give you the
input samples and expected output (or if you want - the problem statement as well).
I've been stuck on that practice problem for over 5 days :(

Comment: Possible typo: should `myvar`'s return statement instead be `return sum((i-m)**2 for i in arr)/l`?

Comment: @PSSolanki How to move to a chat room? I'm new here so I'm sure how to do that. If you can post your input examples, I would like to help.

Comment: @fusion I will do that. Just to let ya know chat.stackoverflow.com allows people to interact. I actually consulted your approach  with kevin yesterday in my favorite [Python Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) and we reached a conclusion that we may need to go with something else (a different approach.) Anyways your'approach made me clear 5 more test cases. (you will know what i'm talking about when you will see the problem statement and expected outputs for input test cases).

Comment: @fusion Join the chat room here - [Join Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220955/a-discussion-on-variance-generators)

You and kevin have explicit write access.

Comment: @kevin Consider joining the room, please :)